# Selecting points inside of fishnet tile and adding its ID to points attribute table using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point-in-polygon

Using **ArcGIS Pro**, I have uploaded a csv file containing **GPS points** and displayed it as XY Data. I have also created a **polygon fishnet of 50x50 tiles**.

What I want is, **for each tile of the grid**, I retrieve the **points** that lay **inside** of it and modify their attribute table so that they include the **tile ID** that they belong to. and I want this to be done **dynamically** if possible (Each entry of the attribute table would have a column called tile containing the tile ID that it belongs to. In other words, I want to spatially group the points together)

The problem is, I'm quite new to ArcGIS pro, I've just started using it. I tried creating a polygon and placing it over some points then using the **select by location** tool (**intersect**) just to get started and it worked just fine (It only selected the points inside). But with a fishnet, it selects the entire grid not just a tile.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Just use the spatial join tool, but make sure the points are single part first. No code required.

Comment: @Hornbydd THANK YOU SO MUCH! you may not know it but you just saved me. I will mention your name in the acknowledgements section xD. Thank you again